# NGINX http to https if only contains certain directory

Tags: nginx

I have been tasked with a couple project.
We have two directories on our server, one is 
http://example.com/app
and the other is
http://example.com/fw

What I have been asked to do, is redirect from http to https if any visitor lands on a page in these two directories (app and fw) 
Here is what I have done so far in the config file. When I added the lines to my config file below 'server' and restarted the site would not come back up. Unfortunately I don't have access to the log files. Appreciate anyone willing to take a look at this

```
location ~ ^/miner/memclub/.+\.html$ {
    rewrite ^(.+)\.html$ /bootstrap.php?file=$1.html last;
    rewrite ^(.+)\.phtml$ /bootstrap.php?file=$1.phtml last;
    error_page 404 = /404.php;
}

server {
server_name site.org;
server_name *.site.org;
location /app {
     if ( $scheme = http ) {
     rewrite ^ https://site.org/app last;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I don't think you can have 2 `server_name`, merge those two lines into one line

```
server_name example.com *.example.com;
```

And to do the https redirect i would recommend using 2 separate servers, you need one listening to port `443` anyway

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com; # which ever you are using
    listen 443 ssl;
    location / {
        # all your https configuration
    }
}
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com:
    listen 80;
    location /app {
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }
    location /fw {
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }
    location / {
        # the rest of the non https configuration
    }
}
```

I know you can merge both `app` and `fw` into one location, but I believe doing it without regex is faster, if you want to do it anyways here it is

```
location /(app|fw) {
    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}
```